# Return SQL query results on the 2nd identical column

Tags: sql, mysql

I am facing a challenge while running a SQL query:

There are 2 tables:

- Sample Table 01

| Ext. Initial ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | start11 |
| 1112 | start12 |
| 1113 | start13 |
| 1114 | start14 |
| 1115 | start15 |
| 1116 | start16 |
| 1117 | start17 |
| 1118 | start18 |
| 1119 | start19 |
| 1120 | start20 |

- Sample Table 02

| Ext. Initial ID | Ext. Level one ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1115 |
| 1112 | 1115 |
| 1113 | 1113 |
| 1114 | 1113 |
| 1115 | 1113 |
| 1116 | 1113 |
| 1117 | 1119 |
| 1118 | 1119 |
| 1119 | 1119 |
| 1120 | 1119 |

"Ext. Initial ID" and "Description" columns are Unique.

Whereas "Ext. Level one ID" is repetitive (but its basically part of "Ext. Initial ID" only)

```
**Query Im using:**


SELECT 

I.external_initial_id,
C.external_level_one_id,
I.description

FROM sample_table_01 AS I

inner join sample_table_02 AS C

ON I.external_initial_id = C.external_initial_id
```

Now, I need results for few ext. Initial IDs only, So, I put them using a filter (in a comma separated manner in a dashboard) and the query comes out to be:

```
The above Query returns the result like this:

| Ext. Initial ID | Ext. Level one ID |  Description |
| --------        | --------          |  --------    |
| 1111            | 1115              | start11      |
| 1112            | 1115              | start12      |
| 1113            | 1113              | start13      | 
| 1114            | 1113              | start14      | 
| 1117            | 1119              | start17      | 
| 1119            | 1119              | start19      |
```

Here, I am getting the "description column" which is linked to Ext. Initial ID in table 01.

However, I want the "description column" for Ext. Level one ID (i.e for the result column from another table).

Desired Output I'm looking for:

| Ext. Initial ID | Ext. Level one ID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1115 | start15 |
| 1112 | 1115 | start15 |
| 1113 | 1113 | start13 |
| 1114 | 1113 | start13 |
| 1117 | 1119 | start19 |
| 1119 | 1119 | start19 |

Comment: You say you need to link "ext level one ID" `1115` with "description" `start15`, however I can't find anything in your sample data which would link them together. Could you please explain the rule behind?

Comment: Hi @MátéJuhász, "ext level one ID" is a same value as "Ext. Initial ID" as you can see in table 02. However, in the desired result, the descripton col is fetching values for "ext. Initial ID" and not for "Ext. Level one ID". Though, its correct, but I need the description for "Ext. Level one ID" as the description is valid for that column too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like this:

`SELECT C.external_initial_id,C.external_level_one_id,I.description FROM sample_table_02 AS C inner join sample_table_01 AS I ON C.external_level_one_id = I.external_initial_id`